# Change the location of Dialogflow Messenger icon

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to know if it's possible to move location of Dialogflow Messenger icon using CSS, currently it's on the bottom right of my website but the scroll up button is overlapping it. [I have attached a screenshot for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQXE5.png)

Comment: Attached link is the documentation but i couldn't find anything on this. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger

Answer (score 0):

This can be changed in the DailogFlow project:
`Settings -> Update Avatar -> Upload the icon`

Answer (score 0):

there is no in-built support for this from DialogFlow Messenger but able to figure out a workaround via JS scripts.

```js
const dfMessenger = document.querySelector('df-messenger');
            dfMessenger.addEventListener('df-messenger-loaded', function () {
                // Handle event
                let dfIcon = dfMessenger?.shadowRoot?.querySelector("#widgetIcon");
                if(dfIcon) {
                    dfIcon.style.bottom = "60px";
                }
            });
```